# Pulling Docker image from private protected repository within bash script

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-compose, repository

I am trying to write a bash script to automatize the setup of a multi-containers environment.
Each container is built from images pulled from a private protected repository.

The problem is that when the script calls for `docker-compose up` for the first time, access to the repository is denied, like if it does not know I have properly done `docker login` before running the script.
If I `docker pull` an image manually, that very image is no longer a problem when the script tries to build its container. But when it has to `docker pull` on its own from a `Dockerfile` definition, it gets `access denied`.

Considering that I would like this script to be portable to other devs' environments, how can I get it to be able to access the repository using the credentials each dev will have already set on its computer with `docker login`?

Comment: It seems like it *should* work. Can you share your script and the error message ? You can redact personal infos as long as it stays consistent in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ~/pwd.txt | docker login <servername> -u <username> --password-stdin
docker pull
```

This reads the password from pwd.txt and logs in to the specified server.
In case you have multiple servers you want to log in you can try:

```
#!/bin/bash
serverlist="server1.com server2.com"
for server in $serverlist; do
    cat ~/${server}_pwd.txt | docker login $server -u <username> --password-stdin
done
docker pull
```

This reads the passwords from files like server1.com_pwd.txt.